# Check for Internet Connectivity when power saver mode is turned on

Tags: android, android-fragments

When power saver mode is turned on, I am bringing my app to foreground.
In onResume of my fragment, I am trying to check whether there is internet connectivity using Connectivity Manager. But I am always getting false even though I am connected to WiFi network.

How to check for internet connectivity when my app is in foreground and power saver mode is turned on?

```
public void onResume() {
    LOG.i("+++++++ OnResume is Called");
    super.onResume();
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    LOG.i("++++++ Active Network Connected :: " + activeNetInfo.isConnected());
}
```

I am always getting "ActiveNetworkConnected" as false when my app is in foreground and power saver mode is turned on. Can somebody please help ?

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. Did you get any solution ?

Comment: Nope we couldn't get any solutions. It returns false only on the very first call.